# Ошибка - не найден соответствующий оператор вызова

Tags: c++, set, merge

Не смог нагуглить почему происходит такая ошибка, сам не могу найти. Скорее всего это связано с `merge`, потому что без этой строчки работает норм. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Полностью ошибка звучит так:
Ошибка  C3889   вызов объекта типа класса "std::less": не найден соответствующий оператор вызова  Программа_2 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\algorithm 6422

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

using lli = long long;
using lld = long double;
using ulli = unsigned long long;
using usi = unsigned short;

//Структуры
struct st_coor
{
    lld x, y, z;
};

struct cmp {
    bool operator() (const st_coor& v1, const st_coor& v2) const noexcept {
        if (v1.x == v2.x && v1.y == v2.y) return v1.z < v2.z;
        else if (v1.x == v2.x) return v1.y < v2.y;
        else return v1.x < v2.x;
    }
};

//Функции
void InputCell(set <st_coor, cmp>& set_cell, usi& cnt_atoms_cell,
               lld& cellside_x, lld& cellside_y, lld& cellside_z);
void InputCube(usi& cubeside_x, usi& cubeside_y, usi& cubeside_z);
void FillCube(set <st_coor, cmp>& set_cube, set <st_coor, cmp>& set_cell,
                usi cubeside_x, usi cubeside_y, usi cubeside_z,
                lld cellside_x, lld cellside_y, lld cellside_z);
void AddDefects(set <st_coor, cmp>& set_cube);
void FillPGU(set <st_coor, cmp>& set_cube, set <st_coor, cmp>& set_PGU,
    usi cubeside_x, usi cubeside_y, usi cubeside_z,
    lld cellside_x, lld cellside_y, lld cellside_z);

//======================================================================

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    //указание элементарной ячейки
    set <st_coor, cmp> set_cell;
    usi cnt_atoms_cell;
    lld cellside_x, cellside_y, cellside_z;
    InputCell(set_cell, cnt_atoms_cell, cellside_x, cellside_y, cellside_z);

    //cоздание решётки
    set <st_coor, cmp> set_cube;
    usi cubeside_x, cubeside_y, cubeside_z;
    InputCube(cubeside_x, cubeside_y, cubeside_z);
    FillCube(set_cube, set_cell, cubeside_x, cubeside_y, cubeside_z, cellside_x, cellside_y, cellside_z);
    
    //Добавление дефектов
    cout << "\nДОБАВЛЕНИЕ ДЕФЕКТОВ\n";
    bool command_defect;
    do {
        AddDefects(set_cube);
        cout << "\nХотите добавить ещё дефект?\n";
        cout << "Введите \"1\",если да, или \"0\", если нет - ";
        cin >> command_defect;
    }
    while (command_defect);

    //Создание ПГУ условий
    cout << "\nДОБАВЛЕНИЕ ПЕРЕОДИЧЕСКИХ ГРАНИЧНЫХ УСЛОВИЙ (ПГУ)\n";
    cout << "\nХотите добавить ПГУ?\n";
    cout << "Введите \"1\",если да, или \"0\", если нет - ";
    bool command_PGU;
    cin >> command_PGU;
    set <st_coor, cmp> set_PGU;
    if (command_PGU) FillPGU(set_cube, set_PGU, cubeside_x, cubeside_y, cubeside_z, cellside_x, cellside_y, cellside_z);
    set <st_coor, cmp> set_all;
    merge(set_cube.begin(), set_cube.end(), set_PGU.begin(), set_PGU.end(), back_inserter(set_all));

    //Запись массива в конфиг для визуализации на питоне
    ofstream conf("config.txt");
    for (const auto& atom : set_all)
    {
        conf << atom.x << endl << atom.y << endl << atom.z << endl;
    }
    conf.close();

    return 0;
}

//======================================================================

//Функции
void InputCell(set <st_coor, cmp>& set_cell, usi& cnt_atoms_cell,
                lld& cellside_x, lld& cellside_y, lld& cellside_z)
{
    cout << "Введите количество атомов в элементарной ячейке - ";
    cin >> cnt_atoms_cell;
    cout << "Введите размеры сторон элементарной ячейки - ";
    cin >> cellside_x >> cellside_y >> cellside_z;
    cout << "Введите координаты атомов элементарной ячейки: " << endl;
    for (int n = 0; n < cnt_atoms_cell; ++n)
    {
        st_coor atom;
        cin >> atom.x >> atom.y >> atom.z;
        set_cell.insert(atom);
    }
}

void InputCube(usi& cubeside_x, usi& cubeside_y, usi& cubeside_z)
{
    cout << "Введите стороны моделируемого куба,\n"
         << "считая в элементарных ячейках - ";
    cin >> cubeside_x >> cubeside_y >> cubeside_z;
}

void FillCube(set <st_coor, cmp> &set_cube, set <st_coor, cmp> &set_cell,
                usi cubeside_x, usi cubeside_y, usi cubeside_z,
                lld cellside_x, lld cellside_y, lld cellside_z)
{
    for (lld x = 0; x < cubeside_x * cellside_x; x += cellside_x)
    {
        for (lld y = 0; y < cubeside_y * cellside_y; y += cellside_y)
        {
            for (lld z = 0; z < cubeside_z * cellside_z; z += cellside_z)
            {
                for (const st_coor& atom : set_cell)
                {
                    set_cube.insert({ atom.x + x, atom.y + y, atom.z + z });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void AddDefects(set <st_coor, cmp>& set_cube)
{
    cout << "\nСписок доступных команд:\n";
    cout << "1. Добавление атомов\n" << "2. Удаление атомов\n" << "3. Сдвиг атомов\n";
    cout << "Введите номер команды - ";
    usi command_add_defect;
    cin >> command_add_defect;
    switch (command_add_defect)
    {
    case 1: //Добавление атомов
        cout << "Введите количество добавляемых атомов - ";
        usi cnt_add_atom;
        cin >> cnt_add_atom;
        cout << "Введите координаты добавляемых атомов атомов:\n";
        for (int n = 0; n < cnt_add_atom; ++n)
        {
            st_coor atom;
            cin >> atom.x >> atom.y >> atom.z;
            set_cube.insert(atom);
        }
        break;

    case 2: //Удаление атомов
        cout << "Введите количество удаляемых атомов - ";
        usi cnt_del_atom;
        cin >> cnt_del_atom;
        cout << "Введите координаты удаляемых атомов:\n";
        for (int n = 0; n < cnt_del_atom; ++n)
        {
            st_coor atom;
            cin >> atom.x >> atom.y >> atom.z;
            if (set_cube.find(atom) == set_cube.end())
            {
                cout << "\nОШИБКА: Атома с введёнными координатами не существует\n";
                cout << "1. Повторить ввод\n" << "2. Отменить ввод\n";
                cout << "Введите номер команды - ";
                usi command_del_defect_error;
                cin >> command_del_defect_error;
                if (command_del_defect_error == 1) --n;
                continue;
            }
            set_cube.erase(set_cube.find(atom));
        }
        break;

    case 3://Сдвиг атомов
        cout << "Введите количество сдвигаемых атомов - ";
        usi cnt_shift_atom;
        cin >> cnt_shift_atom;
        for (int n = 0; n < cnt_shift_atom; ++n)
        {
            cout << "Введите координaты сдвигаемого атома - ";
            st_coor atom;
            cin >> atom.x >> atom.y >> atom.z;
            if (set_cube.find(atom) == set_cube.end())
            {
                cout << "ОШИБКА: Атома с введёнными координатами не существует";
                cout << "1. Повторить ввод\n" << "2. Отменить ввод\n";
                cout << "Введите номер команды - ";
                usi command_shift_defect_error;
                cin >> command_shift_defect_error;
                if (command_shift_defect_error == 1) --n;
                continue;
            }
            cout << "Введите вектор сдвига - ";
            st_coor vec_shift_atom;
            cin >> vec_shift_atom.x >> vec_shift_atom.y >> vec_shift_atom.z;
            set_cube.erase(set_cube.find(atom));
            set_cube.insert({ atom.x + vec_shift_atom.x, atom.y + vec_shift_atom.y,
                atom.z + vec_shift_atom.z });
        }
        break;
    }
}

void FillPGU(set <st_coor, cmp>& set_cube, set <st_coor, cmp>& set_PGU,
                usi cubeside_x, usi cubeside_y, usi cubeside_z,
                lld cellside_x, lld cellside_y, lld cellside_z)
{
    cout << "Введите толщину периодических границ - ";
    lld width_PGU;
    cin >> width_PGU;
    for (st_coor atom : set_cube)
    {
        if (atom.x < width_PGU)
        {
            atom.x += cubeside_x * cellside_x;
            set_PGU.insert(atom);
            if (atom.y < width_PGU)
            {
                atom.y += cubeside_y * cellside_y;
                set_PGU.insert(atom);
                if (atom.z < width_PGU)
                {
                    atom.z += cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                    set_PGU.insert(atom);
                }
                else if (atom.z > cubeside_z * cellside_z - width_PGU)
                {
                    atom.z -= cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                    set_PGU.insert(atom);
                }
            }
            else if (atom.y > cubeside_y * cellside_y - width_PGU)
            {
                atom.y -= cubeside_y * cellside_y;
                set_PGU.insert(atom);
                if (atom.z < width_PGU)
                {
                    atom.z += cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                    set_PGU.insert(atom);
                }
                else if (atom.z > cubeside_z * cellside_z - width_PGU)
                {
                    atom.z -= cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                    set_PGU.insert(atom);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (atom.x > cubeside_x * cellside_x - width_PGU)
        {
            atom.x -= cubeside_x * cellside_x;
            set_PGU.insert(atom);
            if (atom.y < width_PGU)
            {
                atom.y += cubeside_y * cellside_y;
                set_PGU.insert(atom);
                if (atom.z < width_PGU)
                {
                    atom.z += cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                    set_PGU.insert(atom);
                }
                else if (atom.z > cubeside_z * cellside_z - width_PGU)
                {
                    atom.z -= cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                    set_PGU.insert(atom);
                }
            }
            else if (atom.y > cubeside_y * cellside_y - width_PGU)
            {
                atom.y -= cubeside_y * cellside_y;
                set_PGU.insert(atom);
                if (atom.z < width_PGU)
                {
                    atom.z += cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                    set_PGU.insert(atom);
                }
                else if (atom.z > cubeside_z * cellside_z - width_PGU)
                {
                    atom.z -= cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                    set_PGU.insert(atom);
                }
            }
        }

        else if (atom.y < width_PGU)
        {
            atom.y += cubeside_y * cellside_y;
            set_PGU.insert(atom);
            if (atom.z < width_PGU)
            {
                atom.z += cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                set_PGU.insert(atom);
            }
            else if (atom.z > width_PGU)
            {
                atom.z -= cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                set_PGU.insert(atom);
            }
        }
        else if (atom.y > cubeside_y * cellside_y - width_PGU)
        {
            atom.y -= cubeside_y * cellside_y;
            set_PGU.insert(atom);
            if (atom.z < width_PGU)
            {
                atom.z += cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                set_PGU.insert(atom);
            }
            else if (atom.z > width_PGU)
            {
                atom.z -= cubeside_z * cellside_z;
                set_PGU.insert(atom);
            }
        }

        else if (atom.z < width_PGU)
        {
            atom.z += cubeside_z * cellside_z;
            set_PGU.insert(atom);
        }
        else if (atom.z > cubeside_z * cellside_z - width_PGU)
        {
            atom.z -= cubeside_z * cellside_z;
            set_PGU.insert(atom);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет:

```
set_all = set_cube;
set_all.merge(set_PGU);
```

Comment: у set нет метода merge

Comment: @ВладимирПопов он вроде доступен в с++20 или с++17. Укажите в компиляторе новую версию, если это возможно

Comment: спасибо, попробую